# I get the "error 400" return from the flask. When the call comes from the java / eclipse code

Tags: java, flask

I have the project in flask to get a parameter and it works, if I make the call by postman. But if I do it by the java code, it returns error 400.

Flask:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    print("\nPredict......")
    print(request.form)
    print(request.form['textToPredict'])
    print("\nPredict......2")
    print(request.form.get("textToPredict"))
    #print("Text...."+request.form['textToPredict'].toString())
    # new text to predict
    text_to_predict = [request.form['textToPredict'].lower()] #[request.form.get('textToPredict')]  # ["asmatica desde infancia ex fumante 15 am dopc em uso de o2 ha 1 ano em uso de alenia 400 /12  e formoterol 12    2 x dia mvdiminuido sra brn f 2 t s/s cta  rx pfp"]  # este deve retornar CID Z00
    #print("Text....:"+str(text_to_predict))
    # count_vect gera as posições dos vetores de cada palavra do texto.
    new = count_vect.transform(text_to_predict)

    # carrega o modelo treinado
    loaded_model = cPickle.load(open(fname, 'rb'))
    # faz a predição do novo texto de entrada
    result = loaded_model.predict(new)
    print(result)
    # accuracy_score(y_test, result)

    json_dict = request.get_json()
    text = ''.join(result)
    textPredicted = text
    data = {'textPredicted': textPredicted}
    return jsonify(data), 200
```

Output from java(print FLASK code):

```
Predict......
ImmutableMultiDict([('{"textToPredict":"coriza"}', '')])
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2018 16:07:34] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Output from postman(print FLASK code):

```
Predict......
ImmutableMultiDict([('textToPredict', 'coriza, dificuldade em respirar, febre, dor no corpo')])
coriza, dificuldade em respirar, febre, dor no corpo

Predict......2
coriza, dificuldade em respirar, febre, dor no corpo
['J06 ']
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2018 16:20:00] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Java code:

```
@POST
    // @Path("")
    private String predictCid(String predicaoVo) throws IOException {
        System.out.print("\nentrou no método predict");

        try {

            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("textToPredict", predicaoVo);
            String PARAMETROS = "{\ntextToPredict:"+predicaoVo+"\n}";
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict");
            HttpURLConnection postConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            postConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            postConnection.setRequestProperty("content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            postConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            postConnection.setDoInput(true);
            postConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            // Send POST output.
            DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(postConnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(printout, "UTF-8"));
            System.out.print("\nParametros: "+jsonParam.toString());

            writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            //printout.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
            //printout.flush();
            printout.close();

            int responseCode = postConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("POST Response Code :  " + responseCode);
            System.out.println("POST Response Message : " + postConnection.getResponseMessage());


            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(postConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                // print result
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                return response.toString();
            } else {
                System.out.println("POST NOT WORKED");

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "some string just to test"; // just a test
    }
```

So, it seems, my error is in sending the post, when it's made of the java code.

I can not understand the reason for the error. It seems to me that the parameter, is incorrect when arriving at the flask, by the outputs that it presents.

I would like some help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Could you add some detail on server setup?


Like:
Are you running two separate servers?
Are you hitting the correct IP?
Is this a possible CORS issue?

Comment: @Q.Holness The IP is correct, it is local. Flask is local because it is a server only to return this string. But it is consumed by the Java server. So the IP is local, on the same server as the java code.

Comment: I'm guessing the correct IP. These outputs, from FLASK, are where the Python code is.

Comment: I can see a difference in the arrival of POST items. But I can not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java code is not correct because you are trying to send json object string into form url encoded data. Look like your Flask controller expecting form param. you can change your java code like that

```
String urlParam  = "textToPredict="+predicaoVo;
byte[] postData  = urlParam.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );

int dataLength = postData.length;

postConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString(dataLength));

try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(postConnection.getOutputStream())) {
   wr.write(postData);
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Thank you!